# how to create layout as a dialog pop up from down

Tags: android

I want to create a layout as shown below where I can load items in a recycler view. How can it be done?

I am new to android and I checked the type of dialog but somehow didn't find appropriate the appropriate XML code.

help will be appreciated Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The component in the image is called a Bottom Sheet. It is a part of material components by google. You can take a look at how to create Bottom Sheets here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

Here are some things to keep in mind while implementing a bottom sheet: https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#anatomy

Hopefully this helps!